# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method registerDefaultInstance with Firebase Performance and Espresso Instrumented Tests

Tags: android, firebase, android-espresso, firebase-performance

When I adding `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf-ktx:19.1.0'` I cannot start espresso instrumented tests ("app" scheme building ok). When I trying to start Espresso test, I have

```
Test running failed: Process crashed.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method registerDefaultInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;Lcom/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageLite;)V in class Lcom/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageLite
```

But if I'm deleting `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf-ktx:19.1.0'` everything working fine.
How to keep Firebase Performance library and Espresso Instrumented tests?

Comment: Please post the full exception. Also, are you running proguard?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In my case it seems to be caused by `protobuf-lite:3.0.1` dependency from recently updated `androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0'` which I was able to fix with this exclude

```
androidTestImplementation (androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0'){
    exclude module: "protobuf-lite"
}
```

In case of KTX

```
testImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0') {
        exclude(module = "protobuf-lite")
    }
```

Comment: More info about this issue you can see at https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/999

Comment: I'm still getting the issue

Comment: I always thought Espresso 3.4.0 and above simply didn't work. Turns out this was the issue the whole time. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is work:

```
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0") 
{
    exclude(group: "com.google.protobuf", module: "protobuf-lite")
}
```

Comment: But this one will exclude   "protobuf-lite" inside "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0" too, right? I mean espresso will try to use protobuf-lite from app level or will crash.

Answer (score 1):

This is work:

```
androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0') {
    exclude module: "protobuf-lite"
}
androidTestImplementation ('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-accessibility:3.4.0') {
    exclude module: "protobuf-lite"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently got a very similar error while running android detox tests with react native. Excluding the protobuf-lite module resolve it for me.

Changing:
`androidTestImplementation('com.wix:detox:+')`

To:
`androidTestImplementation('com.wix:detox:+') { exclude module: "protobuf-lite" }`

inside of `android/app/build.gradle` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is for those who are using the [barista library](https://github.com/AdevintaSpain/Barista) for UI test

Issue got resolved with the below piece of code

```
androidTestImplementation("com.adevinta.android:barista:4.2.0) {
        exclude("org.jetbrains.kotlin") // Only if you already use Kotlin in your project
        exclude("com.google.protobuf", "protobuf-lite")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, it's the protobuf-lite runtime, which is coming with *androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib* dep.

When inspecting dependencies, it seems that this dep comes in play when running Instumentation test in debug mode (debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath)

```
 ./gradlew app:dependencies
```

Adding following line in apps build.gradle will exclude  it  on debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath configuration and your test should be running fine again :)

```
configurations
{
    debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath.exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf' module: 'protobuf-lite'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you might need to modify how you specify your dependency and use something like this:

```
implementation(Deps.Firebase.performance)
    {
        exclude(group = "com.google.protobuf", module="protobuf-java")
    }
```

Source:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1907

Comment: @ВладимирФишер have you found a solution to this?

Comment: Yes, Nicola. I enabled MultiDex for the project